# Easiest way to plot array of floats

Tags: android

I am not that experienced with Java/Android programming. 
I have an array of floats that i have logged, and i want to plot them against time.
I just want to see what the data looks like, I don't really need to plot it in the app itself, although it would be handy. I am looking for the simplest possible way to do this. 
I have looked around at libraries (graph view and achartengine) which plot graphs in the app, but when i imported them into eclipse, there were errors everywhere on the demo code.
Maybe it would be easier to export the array so I can plot it on the computer, e.g. to a csv file (for excel)? But, I can only find stuff on databases with csv files. Someone please point me in the simplest direction! :-D
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are quite simple.

1. You may draw your values at any `View` by overriding its [`draw(Canvas)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method. The  thing which will take the most time is converting your values to view's coordinates, which is actually primitive algebra.
2. You don't need any tools to generate `*.csv` files - it has very simple format, you may create it by yourself. In your case its content will look like this:

   ```
   "time","value"
   "12300000","78.99"
   "12340000","89.77"
   ...
   ```

Here is the code, which will produce such file:

```
    long[] time = ...; // this contains your time values
    float[] values = ...; // this contains your float values
    File outFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/my_output_file.csv");

    BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile)));
    buffWriter.write("\"time\",\"values\"\n");
    buffWriter.flush();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        buffWriter.write("\"" + time[i] + "\",\"" + values[i] + "\"\n");
        buffWriter.flush();
    }

    buffWriter.close();
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I have looked at a few tutorials on csv files. I suppose i would be better off writing to the file as i fill the array, rather than filling it at the end. Could u be a bit more specific in terms of the code required to do this?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I just tried that, and eclipse doesn't like the 5th line. It gives the following error: "syntax error on token ""\"time\",\"values + \"\n"", delete this token". This is just to make headings for the columns, right? I tried loads of entry formats for the .write, and none worked. I tried leaving it out, and this caused a different error on the 'FileOutputStream' on the line above. "Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor". Any ideas?

Comment: My app is logging analog inputs, which i want to be able to write to a csv file, so i need to write to the file as i read the values, rather than writing as a loop at the end, because you don't know when the connection between phone and brd will b broken. I changed the code to do this, and i **got rid of my previous errors**. When i open the file afterwards, it is completely blank. I left the syntax as you had it.

Comment: I just did a check where i had: 'if (j == 100) {  your code exactly  }' Still, there was nothing in my output file.

Comment: I got it working. I found a way to detect disconnect from the brd, and implemented ur code on detection. Everything working, except tiny thing: i have a third column for another value i am logging, when i copied the format for the 'values' array u listed (which worked for the time and values columns), it gives the value in "", e.g. "3" instead of 3. I have: 'buffWriter.write("\"" + time[i] + "\",\"" + an_array[i] + "\", \"" + an_array2[i] + "\",\n"'