# plotting real time csv data in android

Tags: android, plot, arduino

By using arduino, python serial I am able to log  data from a temp sensor from dev/ttyACM0      into a file timetemp.csv
which looks like

```
Wed Jun 12 12:59:45 2013,27
Wed Jun 12 12:59:46 2013,27
Wed Jun 12 12:59:47 2013,27
Wed Jun 12 12:59:48 2013,27
Wed Jun 12 12:59:49 2013,27
Wed Jun 12 12:59:50 2013,26
```

Next thing I want is to show a realtime plot of time-sensordata preferably in android client by setting up the system(where the csv file resides) as a server...Will this be possible using the androidplot or any other plot utility like Rgraph...What are your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use androidplot for it. It should be possible. Also you can do it by yourself.
You can look into this discussion for reference code.
[Easiest way to plot array of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423685/easiest-way-to-plot-array-of-floats)